# Running two http servers, but binding to different interfaces?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx

How can a pair of http servers be configured to both listen on port 80, but on different interfaces on the same server?

Specifically, I would like to run nginx and apache on one machine (CentOS 6) for different applications on different IPs.

I believe that by default Apache binds to 0.0.0.0, responding to requests on all inbound traffic. How could this scenario be implemented?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Apache, change a `Listen 80` to `Listen X.X.X.X:80`.

In nginx, change a `listen 80;` to `listen Y.Y.Y.Y:80;`.

Comment: well, shoot - that was substantially simpler than I had yet seen in the documentation :) .. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once a service bound  to a specific port, no other services will be permitted to bind to that port. You may have to use different port.

What kind of a scenario you are trying to implement? Is that Nginx load balancing?